# How to deploy a file from Visual Studio to an accessible folder in XAML Metro App?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, .net-4.5

I have XAML Metro app. I need to deploy a static file to be read on every app launch. I have access to certain paths only (eg LocalStorage and InstalledLocation..is that right?)

**How do I make VS 2012 to deploy that file (rtf document) to the location which can be read by the app ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good solution is to place the file in the Assets subfolder of your VS solution and access with:

```
Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(@"Assets\file.rtf")
```

[Documentation from Microsoft on InstalledLocation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.package.installedlocation)

e.g.

```
var file = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.
                     Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(@"Assets\file.rtf");
result = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
```

Nicely demonstrated in the following blog post:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/metroapps/archive/2012/07/15/access-your-application-assets-folder.aspx

also good information here:

http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/06/windows-8-how-to-read-files-in-winrt.html